# Is our Identity Server necessary if we don't need SSO or OAuth 2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver4

Our infrastructure looks like this:

- IdentityServer4 Auth Server,
- .NET Core 2.2 web api
- Angular SPA1
- Angular SPA2
- MVC MVCApp1

My understanding is that the purpose of Identity Server 4 is to do one of 2 things:

1. Single Sign On.  So you sign in on SPA1 you are still signed in on SPA2 and MVCApp1.
2. Authorize users in 3rd party apps to sign in via an OAuth 2.0 flow and grant our data to a 3rd party app.

For #1, no one should every stay signed in because SPA1 and SPA2 and MVCApp1 all basically have different end users.  AKA we don't need SSO.
For #2, not relevant because we will never allow this.

This means that we have a IdentityServer 4 project that feels like overkill and is very difficult to debug.  Things like users bookmarking the auth server instead of the app, redirects randomly failing, and so on.

My question is can I just switch over to user authentication in the API instead and kill this Identity Server?  We can easily add an Authenticate Endpoint in the API. Is there anything less secure about that?

Something like this:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]UserDto userDto)
    {
        var user = _userService.Authenticate(userDto.Username, userDto.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return Unauthorized();

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] 
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        // return basic user info (without password) and token to store client side
        return Ok(new {
            Id = user.Id,
            Username = user.Username,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            Token = tokenString
        });
    }
```

Comment: Would also appreciate explanations of down-votes so I know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer your question whether it is necessary, as this may be opinion based. But I have some remarks.

IdentityServer is an implementation of OpenID Connect on top of OAuth2. If you don't want to use OpenID Connect and OAuth2 then IdentityServer may not be the right tool.

However, IdentityServer does more than just implement the specifications. It is also about seperating responsibilities.

With a central authority, applications don't need to implement login functionality. In the simplest flow the user logs in on IdentityServer giving the user a token and with that token the client can access the resource on behalf of the user. All the resource has to do is verify the authority.

The single responsibility is a good design, seperates login logic from business logic (seperation of concerns) and creates a more secure environment. SSO is just a 'side effect' that can be switched off. The resource and the client should not have access to the identity tables.

But it is also about protecting your resources. With IdentityServer it is quite easy to configure which client has access to what resource, using the most appropriate flow.

IdentityServer takes care of authentication and basic authorization. Where authentication is the responsibility of IdentityServer. As a result, all users have access to each client/resource. Authorization is actually a concern of the resource. That's why they've come up with a [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/).

With [Asp.Net Core authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction) you'll have many options to implement authorization.

I can't tell you what to do and I'm sure everything is possible. But when you take a look of design principles then I would prefer seperation of concerns.

About your code, a seven days window of access is quite large. Especially if you are unable to revoke the token.

About users linking the wrong page, well you can't prevent everything.

Comment: Thank you, this was the sort of insight I was looking for.  I still don't feel like Identity Server is the right fit for our environment, it has not been "easy" to configure clients, and our environment is as simple as it gets.